# gradle is not created while importing from exisiting source in android studio

Tags: android

I have cloned an android project from `github`. When I tried to import it into the android studio a window is appeared asking

1) create a project from existing source or

2) import project from an external model.

If I select first option gradle is not created. If I select the second option it asks for the gradle home path. What should I do? how to import the project with `Gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

Choose 1st option and choose `build.gradle` file which is present in Project directory folder and paste this code `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'` in dependencies and rebuild project .
[image]

Comment: there is no option to select buil.gradle file.

Comment: i screenshort your post , its right , see my screen short , i think you importing eclipse project in android Studio

Comment: just wait i am trying

Comment: I think it may be eclipse project. I cloned from https://github.com/petmongrels/android-ivr

Comment: friend this are modules not a project . if you want to use then you have to download these module and import in your android project.

Comment: No Problem because every legend was noob at beginner .

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting screenshot how I'm importing cloned project from. Please check whether am doing any mistake or not.

[importing project from existing source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvzF3.png)
[Selected yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzvBU.png)
[source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47HaZ.png)
[lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqOI7.png)
[selected overwrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc57u.png)
[default 1.8 sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndb6g.png)
[finish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ww0.png)
[directory of android-ivr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYrDV.png)